# Castle interceptors: How to add an interceptor to all registered types?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, aop, interceptor, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm registering several types one-by-one:

```
container.Register(
     Component.For<IService1>().ImplementedBy<ServiceImpl1>(),
     Component.For<IService2>().ImplementedBy<ServiceImpl2>(),
     Component.For<IService3>().ImplementedBy<ServiceImpl3>(),
     Component.For<IService4>().ImplementedBy<ServiceImpl4>()
     );
```

Is there a way to register an interceptor for all types of this assembly that have been registered? I don't want to register all types by convention as `AllTypes` does. I'd just like to add an interceptor without writing

```
.Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForType<DummyInterceptor>())
            .SelectedWith(new FooInterceptorSelector()).Anywhere
```

zillions of times.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As [suggested by Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7930944/2646573), this can be achieved using custom [ComponentModel construction contributors](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/componentmodel-construction-contributors.md).

First, note that

```
...
    .Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForType<DummyInterceptor>())
        .SelectedWith(new FooInterceptorSelector())
        .Anywhere
```

is basically equivalent to

```
...
    .SelectInterceptorsWith(new FooInterceptorSelector())
    .Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForType<DummyInterceptor>())
        .Anywhere
```

that is, associating an `IInterceptorSelector` with a `ComponentModel` is independent from registering interceptors that will be selected using the `IInterceptorSelector`. Moreover, each `ComponentModel` may only have a single interceptor selector.

Because of this separation, the problem is best solved using two independent contributors -- one for registering interceptors, and another for registering an interceptor selector.

The first one is basically the same as shown in [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7930944/2646573). However, it should not be necessary to add a `DependencyModel` for the interceptor, since the interceptor should already have been registered with the container using something like

```
container.Register(Component.For<DummyInterceptor>().LifestyleTransient());
```

so it could look something like

```
using Castle.Core;
using Castle.MicroKernel;
using Castle.MicroKernel.ModelBuilder;

...

public class InterceptorContributor : IContributeComponentModelConstruction
{
    private readonly InterceptorReference interceptor;

    public InterceptorContributor(InterceptorReference interceptor)
    {
        this.interceptor = interceptor;
    }

    public void ProcessModel(IKernel kernel, ComponentModel model)
    {
        if (...)
        {
            model.Interceptors.Add(interceptor)
        }
    }
}
```

or if you want to be able to register multiple interceptors in one go, it is possible to take advantage of the existing implementation of `InterceptorDescriptor`, and instead do:

```
using System;

using Castle.Core;
using Castle.MicroKernel;
using Castle.MicroKernel.ModelBuilder;
using Castle.MicroKernel.ModelBuilder.Descriptors;

...

public class InterceptorsContributor : IContributeComponentModelConstruction
{
    private readonly Predicate<ComponentModel> predicate;
    private readonly IComponentModelDescriptor interceptorsDescriptor;

    public InterceptorsContributor(Predicate<ComponentModel> predicate, params InterceptorReference[] interceptors)
    {
        this.predicate = predicate ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));
        interceptorsDescriptor = new InterceptorDescriptor(interceptors);
    }

    public void ProcessModel(IKernel kernel, ComponentModel model)
    {
        if (predicate.Invoke(model))
        {
            interceptorsDescriptor.BuildComponentModel(kernel, model);
            interceptorsDescriptor.ConfigureComponentModel(kernel, model);
        }
    }
}
```

For registering an `IInterceptorSelector`, the contributor could either be implemented by doing what `InterceptorSelectorDescriptor` does:

```
public void ProcessModel(IKernel kernel, ComponentModel model)
{
    if (...)
    {
        var options = model.ObtainProxyOptions();
        options.Selector = new InstanceReference<IInterceptorSelector>(selector);
    }
}
```

or by using the `InterceptorSelectorDescriptor` directly:

```
using System;

using Castle.Core;
using Castle.DynamicProxy;
using Castle.MicroKernel;
using Castle.MicroKernel.ModelBuilder;
using Castle.MicroKernel.ModelBuilder.Descriptors;

...

public class InterceptorSelectorContributor : IContributeComponentModelConstruction
{
    private readonly Predicate<ComponentModel> predicate;
    private readonly IComponentModelDescriptor interceptorSelectorDescriptor;

    public InterceptorSelectorContributor(Predicate<ComponentModel> predicate, IInterceptorSelector selector)
    {
        this.predicate = predicate ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));

        var selectorRef = new InstanceReference<IInterceptorSelector>(selector);
        interceptorSelectorDescriptor = new InterceptorSelectorDescriptor(selectorRef);
    }

    public void ProcessModel(IKernel kernel, ComponentModel model)
    {
        if (predicate.Invoke(model))
        {
            interceptorSelectorDescriptor.BuildComponentModel(kernel, model);
            interceptorSelectorDescriptor.ConfigureComponentModel(kernel, model);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How would you specify the .SelectedWith when using the ComponentModel contributor?
I can add an interceptor for all methods by doing this.

```
public class MyContributor : IContributeComponentModelConstruction 
{
    public void ProcessModel(IKernel kernel, ComponentModel model)
    {
        model.Dependencies.Add(new DependencyModel(DependencyType.Service, null, typeof(MyInterceptor), false));
        model.Interceptors.AddFirst(InterceptorReference.ForType<MyInterceptor>());
    }
}
```

Comment: The model.Implementation contains the list of methods of my object, but how would I add the interceptor for some methods only?

Comment: Dan, this is a question, not an answer. Please ask it as a separate question.

Comment: It's actually the same question as the OP, the answer is only partial